# Call javascript function after two button presses

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to programme a Duolingo-esque web game. In one scenario after two button presses, a function should be called to further progress. But I've been struggling to find any solutions online or figure it out by myself since this is the first time I'm ever experimenting with javascript.

For scenarios with a single answer, I've been using this function which is being called after a single button press and works just fine:

```
function answer (URL) {
    setTimeout( function() { window.location = URL }, 3500 );
    document.getElementById("answerDisplay").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("buttonCorrectAnswer").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('video').play();
  }
```

If been trying to find a solution by checking if "answerDisplayOne" and "answerDisplayTwo" are both visible and then calling a function but with no success:

```
function answerOne() {
  document.getElementById("answerDisplyOne").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("buttonCorrectAnswerOne").style.display = "none";
}

function answerTwo() {
  document.getElementById("answerDisplayTwo").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("buttonCorrectAnswerTwo").style.display = "none";
}


if ( $("#answerDisplayOne").css('display') == 'inline' && $("#answerDisplayTwo").css('display') == 'inline'){
  function delayTwo (URL) {
    setTimeout( function() { window.location = URL }, 3500 );
    document.getElementById('video').play();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your ` if` block has a function declaration inside it -  that function will not execute if the conditional is true, it will merely be declared. If you want `delayTwo` to execute when the conditions of the `if` block are met, get rid of `function delayTwo (URL) ` and its associated braces `{}`. Just put the code to be executed inside the `if` block like this: `if(conditions){...commands here... }`

Comment: Like this? I tried it but the video doesn't play when the two Answeres are visible?  ):

```
if ( $("hiddenButtonOne").css('display') == 'inline' && $("#hiddenButtonTwo").css('display') == 'inline'){
  document.getElementById('video').play();
}
```

Comment: That's the correct structure yes, but once run the if block is forgotten so you need monitor your conditions continually. The usual way is to add an event listender and put your if block inside it. For example, you mention button presses, an event listener set up for the button will execute the code inside when pressed. I'll put an example in the answer box. Hopefully it will give you enough to progress with your exact example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If been trying to find a solution by checking if "answerDisplayOne" and "answerDisplayTwo" are both visible and then calling a function but with no success:

This happens because you check the condition only once¹:

```
if ( $("#answerDisplayOne").css('display') == 'inline' && $("#answerDisplayTwo").css('display') == 'inline'){
  function delayTwo (URL) {
    setTimeout( function() { window.location = URL }, 3500 );
    document.getElementById('video').play();
  }
}
```

Means it checks the condition and defines a function `delayTwo` IF `#answerDisplayOne` and `#answerDisplayTwo` both have the css property "display" set to "inline". This is not what you want.

You want to check the condition every time the user presses a button:

```
function answerOne() {
  document.getElementById("answerDisplyOne").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("buttonCorrectAnswerOne").style.display = "none";
  check();
}

function answerTwo() {
  document.getElementById("answerDisplayTwo").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("buttonCorrectAnswerTwo").style.display = "none";
  check();
}

function check() {
  if ($("#answerDisplayOne").css('display') == 'inline' && $("#answerDisplayTwo").css('display') == 'inline'){
    setTimeout( function() { window.location = URL }, 3500 );
    document.getElementById('video').play();
  }
}
```

¹ by once I literally mean once. JavaScript is executed from top to bottom. That's why we use event listeners to execute code once something happened. We can't know in advance when the user will click a button can we?

Answer (score 0):

If you need two independent events to trigger a third, you need to monitor both events and have some means of remembering their history. Each time one of the events happens, you check to see if the other event has happened previously and, if so, trigger the third. If not, you need to remember the event the has happened until the other event is detected. (I think you get this but may be unclear as to how to do this in javascript).

My working snippet below is an example where two red boxes are drawn. If either is clicked it will change but a third box will not change unless both are clicked. It doesn't matter which order the two boxes were clicked. In this example, 'memory' of earlier clicks is done by checking whether the other box has already changed.

Crucially, the example illustrates how to set up event listeners to constantly monitor change. They are functions applied to page ojects that take two arguments 1) the event to listen for, in this case `click'` but it could be `change` or `mouseover` etc and 2) the action to perform when the event is detected. Commonly, as in this example, an arrow or orfan function can be included as the actual argument (but a reference to an external function will work too).

```js
// make references to objects on page:
const firstTarget = document.getElementById('target1');
const secondTarget = document.getElementById('target2');
const output = document.getElementById('output');

// set event listeners for click on first target:
firstTarget.addEventListener('click', event => {
event.target.style="background:yellow";
event.target.innerHTML="1st clicked";
checkStatus();
}); // end event listener 1;

// set event listeners for click on second target:
secondTarget.addEventListener('click', event => {
event.target.style="background:green";
event.target.innerHTML="2nd clicked";
checkStatus();
}); // end event listener 2;

function checkStatus() {
  if (firstTarget.innerHTML=="1st clicked" && secondTarget.innerHTML=="2nd clicked") {
   output.innerHTML = "BOTH CLICKED!";
   output.style="background:red";
   } // end if block;
} // end checkStatus function;
```

```css
div {
 display: inline-block;
 background: red;
 width: 80px;
 height: 30px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 5px;
}
#output {
 background: white;
 width: 195px;
 height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div id="target1">click me</div>
<div id="target2">click me</div>
<br>
<div id="output"></div>
```